# How to avoid '[xcb] unknown sequence number' error in a wxPython application

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, user-interface, wxpython

I have a following situation.
I have to snatch a video stream from a camera and draw it onto wx.Panel().
The frames come in as Pil.Image() objects and have some processing done on them before showing up on screen.
This means that, if done directly, the video is shown in slow motion or being flickerry.

I devised two methods that work nicely on Windows.

1.
Using two wx.Timer()s to tick the worker functions.
One of these is a frame snatcher and gets the frames from camera, in a predefined framerate, makes necessary changes to each, turns them into wx.Bitmap()s and puts them onto displaying queue.
The second starts a bit later, after X number of frames are on the queue ready.
So, in displaying queue the video is prepared for drawing, and it goes smoothly. The second function takes each frame (wx.Bitmap()) from displaying queue, puts it into an attribute of an object with wx.Panel() and tells the object to Update(), i.e. draw the image on the wx.Panel() and to the Panel() to Refresh() itsself.
This works because the drawing is very fast. The resizing and other stuff and converting to wx.Bitmap() is slower, so this solves the flickering/slow motion.
The drawback is a little bit too large stream starting delay. Therefore, the stream has big latency.
And possible latency with getting other wx events like from keyboard and mouse, thus making the GUI, SOMETIMES, sluggish.

2.
The second method is using threads in a similar manner.
Two worker threads are used and two queues.
First snatches frames from the camera and puts them onto a queue. The second gets each from the first one's queue, does its job, turns them into wx.Bitmap()'s and puts them onto a displaying queue.
A wx.Timer() is used to get frames (wx.Bitmap()'s) from displaying queue, push them into viewing object and request drawing and refreshing of the viewing wx.Panel() as described above.
No thread is drawing directly to the screen. Main thread is doing it in a Timer() as it should be.
In this way, more work is thrown to memory and CPU which leaves GUI at leasure.
No big latency and no flickers.
Drawback is that it is CPU intensive and memory consuming.

Now, the problem is that both methods work just fine on Windows, the second being displayed in real time, the first having no real trouble with user input.
But, on Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Lite with only X server) the first method works nice, but UI events are late. Very late. Kernel gets them, but my App catches them only after I disconnect the camera. Then they come in all at once. Awful!
So you cannot stop the video or do anything else before manually disconnecting the camera and causing more trouble.
Is that the X's problem or simply a matter of resources, I don't know yet.

As the little thing has a CPU with 4 cores, I'd like to use the second method.
However I get the following error from X:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
```

I have some ideas what I can change in my threaded version to avoid the crash. Some functions within my threads are touching the Widgets a little, so I expect when I remove them the error will go away.
But what I didn't find anywhere on the internet is, how to call XInitThreads() or something that would do the necessary trick, from wxPython.
I could call it from xlib directly, but what would happen then to the wxPython's internal structure? Would it cause a mess?
My program is thread safe. But X thinks that it is cleverer than me. :D

This error is not well "documented" on the internet. Nobody offers any solutions except to modify codes not to use threads. The trouble is that I found out that applications started getting this error after working correctly for years because of Xorg update.
Sometimes, don't use threads is easier said than done.

I won't post code examples. I already wrote too much and the code wouldn't improve your understanding of the issue.
I only want to know, for other's sake, and out of curiosity, how to do it? What would be an equivalent of calling XInitThreads()?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I would have posted the answer otherwise. What is worse I discovered that the method I initially thought will be my solution wasn't because X kept reacting at the slightest sign of wx functions being used in a thread. And this included wx.BitmapFromBuffer() or wx.Bitmap().CopyToBuffer() or any similar function/method for image conversion. I have no idea why as these would surely have to be thread-safe. I.e. they do not interact with the main loop, use events or otherwise influence the current drawing on the screen. They might use X to access the hardware acceleration though.

Comment: @Gabrielle : So I blended two methods I mentioned in my Q into a new one by putting camera capture and PIL manipulations in a thread/threads and conversion to wx.Bitmap() and drawing in the main loop using the timer. It's not perfect, events are still late but accessible I.e. the interface does not freeze completely while showing the stream. I would like to know the answer to my Q very much, but nobody is answering and I have no time to dig through wxWidgets and X's code.